# How to extract a record in a text on string match in a file using Bash

Tags: linux, windows, bash

I have a text file `sample.txt` as:

```
=====record1
title:javabook
price:$120
author:john
path:d:
=====record2
title:.netbook
author:paul
path:f:
=====record3
author:john
title:phpbook
subject:php
path:f:
price:$150
=====record4
title:phpbook
subject:php
path:f:
price:$150
```

From this I want to split the data based on author. It should split into two files which contain:

```
test1.txt

=====record1
    title:javabook
    price:$120
    author:john
    path:d:
=====record3
    author:john
    title:phpbook
    subject:php
    path:f:
    price:$150
```

and

```
test2.txt

=====record2
    title:.netbook
    author:paul
    path:f:
```

I want to dynamically classify the main `sample.txt` file into subfiles based on the author field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`, store the fields in variables. When the record marker is reached, write the fields into the appropriate file (using author's name).

`-F:` specifies the fields are delimited on ":"

This line `$1 ~ /author/ { author=$2 }` if the first field of a line is "author" then store the value in the author variable. This is required as there must be an author named file to write the record to.

Using `substr`() to extract the first five characters, if the beginning of record marker "=====" if found then the data (stored in the `rec` variable) is written to the appropriate author file.

```
 awk -F: '
    $1 ~ /author/ { author=$2; }
    {
        if (substr($1,0,5) == "=====" && author != "") {
            print rec >> (author".txt")
            rec=$0; author=""
        }
        else
            rec=rec "\n" $0
    }
    END { if (author != "") print rec >> (author".txt") }
    ' authors.txt
```

Comment: thanks its working can you explain me the code please?

Comment: You are welcome - more explanation now added.

Comment: thanks, i have one more doubt,my text file consists of 10 records and each record has 15 to 20 fields and all the records does not have same number of fields.so, can i use same code to my text file also?please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: and what is the use of this line "if (length(title) > 0)", why only title has been considered....

Comment: You will need to write some additional code to cope with the 15 to 20 fields. If the fields follow the same format then that should be a simple task. Why length(title) > 0? My reasoning was if a record had a title it must be a valid record.

Comment: how can i validate the record if some of my records does not have title field

Comment: I've modified solution to cope with the final record (the `END` block). Also added a condition variable `startOfProcessing` which replaces the length(title)>0 check. The purpose of the if statement now is merely to suppress writing to file for the first record marker. If this is useful to you , an upvote would be nice :) thanks

Comment: your first code is working only if file consists of four records

Comment: I've refactored the code which simplifies everything :)

Comment: thanks alot for the code but this code displaying the records which does not contain author field

Comment: How can you write the records to an author file without an author?

Comment: with your latest code i am getting the records which does not contain the author field. for example in john.txt file i am getting                 =====record1
title:javabook
price:$120
author:john
path:d:
=====record3
author:john
title:phpbook
subject:php
path:f:
price:$150
=====record4
title:phpbook
subject:php
path:f:
price:$150                                                                  last record is not having author field but the record is displaying in john.txt file